# Condition variable not waking up when used with a chrono::duration<float>

Tags: c++, c++-chrono, condition-variable

Setting a condition variable to wait for a duration of type `chrono::duration<float>` results in the condition variable not waking up, while it wakes up fine with a `chrono::duration<int>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

void int_version()
{
   mutex my_mutex;
   unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);
   condition_variable my_cv;

   chrono::duration<int> my_duration(5);

   // this_thread::sleep_for(my_duration);
   my_cv.wait_for(my_lock, my_duration);
   cout << "Int version finished" << endl;;
}

void float_version()
{
   mutex my_mutex;
   unique_lock<mutex> my_lock(my_mutex);
   condition_variable my_cv;

   chrono::duration<float> my_duration(5);

   // this_thread::sleep_for(my_duration);
   my_cv.wait_for(my_lock, my_duration);
   cout << "Float version finished" << endl;;
}

int main()
{
    thread float_thread(float_version);
    float_thread.detach();

    thread int_thread(int_version);
    int_thread.detach();

    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(10));
    cout << "10 secs elapsed" << endl;
}
```

I can't reproduce this behaviour with just `this_thread::sleep_for`, in this case both versions wake up fine.

Also, sometimes, instead of not waking up, the float version will wake up instantly without waiting 5secs. I guess it could be a spurious wake-up, but I doubt it since it never happens with the int version, and from the few tests I have done, when I try to put it in a while loop to check for spurious wake-ups it seems to constantly wake-up.

So what is happening? Am I misunderstanding something obvious about `chrono::duration<float>`? Am I doing something wrong with my condition variables? With the threads?

Compiled on Ubuntu 16.04 with GCC 7.2 and -std=c++17 -pthread.

Comment: It seems to be a bug for libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68519

Comment: Thanks! Guess it answers my question... so if you want to put this as an aswer I'll accept it. Still weird that a 2 years old bug like this hasn't been investigated.

Comment: Update: Should be fixed in GCC 8 (https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68519).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your codes. It is a [bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68519) of libstdc++.

Answer (score 4):

I now think this is not a libstdc++ bug after all.

The standard specifies that `std::condition_variable::wait_for(rel_time)` must be exactly equivalent to `wait_until(chrono::steady_clock::now() + rel_time)`.

The problem is that the `steady_clock` might have a very high resolution (the standard leaves it unspecified, but libstdc++ uses `std::chrono::nanoseconds` as the `steady_clock::duration` type). When the type of `rel_time` is `duration<float>` the result of `steady_clock::now() + rel_time` is `duration<float, steady_clock::period>`. For libstdc++, that period is `std::nano` which means that the result is a `float` that holds the number of nanoseconds since the 1st of January 1970. That's a lot of nanoseconds. Far more than can be exactly represented by a `float`. A `float` can only exactly represent integers up to 2<sup>23</sup> which is **much** smaller than the number of nanoseconds since 1970.

The consequence is that the `float` value has to be rounded, and might be a value several seconds before `steady_clock::now()`, in which case the timeout happens immediately (instead of waiting for one second). Or it might be several seconds after `steady_clock::now()`, in which case the timeout happens much later than one second.

So basically `chrono::duration<float>` is not a useful type if you are going to use it in arithmetic with high resolution times (such as those from a high resolution clock). The resolution of `std::chrono::system_clock` and `std::chrono::steady_clock` is up to the implementation, so you should not assume that you can safely use `chrono::duration<float>` with clocks provided by the system.

It "works" with GCC 6.5 and 7.4 and later versions, but only because we deliberately do something different from what the standard requires. That means the fix is non-standard and not portable, and `duration<float>` should still be used with caution.